# What resources can I use for learning character decomposition?

Tags: characters, character-components

I'm developing a set of tools meant to aid in learning Chinese characters and I realized that I don't know a good dataset containing character decomposition. Ideally it should be comprehensive (or have as good coverage as possible), machine-readable and available for free (creative commons?). So far I know about [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) and [Make Me a Hanzi](https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi/). What are the other ones?

Comment: Please note that this kind of decomposition is merely graphical. A lot of the time they don’t reveal how the character functions at all. See [this related question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/chinese-character-decomposition/30266#30266).

Answer (score 3):

you may try the 拆字字典:

http://www.kaifangcidian.com/han/chaizi

eg:

### 【彎】 wan1    〖絲 言 弓 彎〗〖糹 言 糹 弓 彎〗

[http://www.kaifangcidian.com/han/chaizi/彎](http://www.kaifangcidian.com/han/chaizi/%E5%BD%8E)

have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

CHISE (http://www.kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/projects/chise/ids/index.html) is one of the most comprehensive ones available, containing decompositons for almost all characters in the [CJK unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block)).

Comment: Thanks! What's the license for it?

Comment: @d33tah the only thing I can find is that it's [open source](http://www.chise.org/index.en.html) and [copyrighted](http://www.chise.org/ids-find)...maybe I didn't look in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/amake/cjk-decomp or
https://github.com/cjkvi/cjkvi-ids is what you're looking for. Licenses are included in the repos. The IDS decomposition is newer but licensing seems a bit unclear. Then again, Chinese characters haven't changed since the first repo, cjk-decomp, was created, use that perhaps.